# current user not shown after login on live server in wordpress that work on localhost

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<div id="extended-menu" class="main-menu">
    <ul class="main-menu">
<?php 
            if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                global $userdata;
                $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 
                $user_name = $current_user->display_name;
                $user_id = $current_user->ID; // You can set $user_id to any users, but this gets the current users ID.
                $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
            ?>  
            <?php
                global $redux_demo; 
                if(isset($redux_demo['page-url-my-account'])) {
                $my_account_link = $redux_demo['page-url-my-account'];
                if(!empty($my_account_link)) {
            ?>
            function show_loggedin_function( $atts ) {
                <li class="first">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $my_account_link ); ?>" class="my-account-button" title="My Account">
                    <?php  $author_avatar_url = get_user_meta($user_id, "user_meta_image", true); ?>
                    <b><?php _e( "Hi", "themesdojo" ); ?>, <?php echo $user_name; ?></b>                                
                </a>                

            <ul class="sub-menu right-submenu" style="opacity: 0; display: none;">
            <?php
                    global $redux_demo; 
                    $upload_event = $redux_demo['page-url-upload-event'];
                    $upload_event_bttn = $redux_demo['menu-upload-event'];
        if(!empty($upload_event) AND $upload_event_bttn == 1) {
        ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $upload_event ); ?>" style="min-width: 116px;"><?php _e( "Add New Event", "themesdojo" ); ?></a></li> 
    <?php } ?>
<!--    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $my_account_link ); ?>" style="min-width: 116px;"><?php printf( __( 'My Account', 'themesdojo' )); ?></a></li>-->

<li><a href="http://multiple3231.com/profile/" style="min-width: 116px;"><?php printf( __( 'Club Profile', 'themesdojo' )); ?></a></li>

<li><a href="http://multiple3231.com/dashboard/" style="min-width: 116px;"><?php printf( __( 'Profile Settings', 'themesdojo' )); ?></a></li>
<li><a href="http://multiple3231.com/reporting/" style="min-width: 116px;"><?php printf( __( 'MMAR Reporting', 'themesdojo' )); ?></a></li>                                         
 <li><a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(get_option('siteurl')); ?>"><?php printf( __( 'Log out', 'themesdojo' )); ?></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>

                                    <?php } } ?>

                                <?php } else { ?>

                                    <li class="first"><a href="#" id="top-menu-login" class="top-menu-login"><?php _e( 'Login', 'themesdojo' ); ?></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" id="top-menu-register" class="top-menu-register"><?php _e( '', 'themesdojo' ); ?></a></li>

                                    <script type="text/javascript">

                                        jQuery(function($) {

                                            document.getElementById('top-menu-login').addEventListener('click', function(e) {

        jQuery('#popup-td-login').css('display', 'block');
            e.preventDefault();

    });

    document.getElementById('top-menu-register').addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    jQuery('#popup-td-register').css('display', 'block');
        e.preventDefault();

    });

    });

                                    </script>

                                <?php } ?>  

                            </ul>

                        </div>
```

that is the code not working on live server in word press it work properly on localhost after login does not shown user name on live and after hover on current username sub menu does not open what is the issue on please help me someone.

current user not shown after login on live server in wordpress that work on localhost

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
global $current_user;
echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . '<br />';
echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';
echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . '<br />';
echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . '<br />';
echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID;
```